# Where does this javascript function get its data?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm relatively new to javascript. Right now, I'm trying to wrap my head around embedded functions and the syntax looks strange (I keep on incorrectly trying to rely on my Java knowledge to figure it out) but I'm getting the hang of it.

I do have one hangup, thus far. I'm looking at working code that has a function very similar to this:

```
    function test(){
            return function(d, i) {
               ...
            };
    }
```

My question is, where in the world does the data pertaining to the return function come from? I understand that data in an embedded function can be passed from its encapsulating parent, but it looks as though the parent function has no data to actually pass considering it has no parameters of its own!

As a note, I looked through all of the other "Questions that may already have your answer" and couldn't find anything that related to my problem. I saw a few that were close but none that hit the nail on its head. A lot of those had a parent/encompassing function that had parameters of its own.

Comment: [Higher order function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

Comment: `function (d, i) { }` doesn't _do_ anything with either `d` nor `i`. It simply says "create a marker for _what to do when I get this data_". None of the code inside of an inner `function (...) { ... }` is executed until the function is called with `(the_func)(the_d, the_I)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! This function is pretty nested in the grand scheme of things so it's proving hard to pinpoint from where the data originates but I'm slowly digging down into it and sorting it out! Your comments have definitely led me down the correct path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `test()` is returning a function, not executing.  So the parameters would be provided by whoever invokes the return function.

```
function test() {
    return function(d, i) {
        ...
    };
}    

var innerFunc = test();

var result = innerFunc(1, 2);  // or call or apply
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! You're correct, the code I'm looking at has a cascade of invocations and callbacks so it's proving difficult to pinpoint where the data is originating from.